# Can anyone help id this partial build/set?

Tags: star-wars, set-identification

I found this partial set bagged at Savers, looked interesting. But searching thru peeron, I cannot figure out what set this might belong to. Is anybody familiar with what set this might be associated with ? Back and front designations are really just arbitrary, as I don't exactly know what I have here. The black bricks hanging out on the top of the "back" side view are technic bricks 1x16 with holes. The sides of the base, if you will, are composed of 6 technic bricks 1x14 with holes, 3 on each side.

[image: Front View]

[image: Back Side View]

[image: Side view]

Answer (score 6):

This is from the [Clone Turbo Tank](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8098-1).

[image]

Comment: You nailed it gev, thank you for the quick response (so much for the guidance/recommendation on not posting comments like +1 or thanks). Peeron doesn't have an inventory, etc for this set, 8098-1, although its listed as a set from 2010. Now, off to find out how much I'll have to pay for 10 of those tires !